# Condensing Logarithmic Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation is $4log_{3}(y+1)+2log_{3}(y-1)-3log_{3}(y^2-1)-log_{3}(y)$. I went to tutoring this morning and my teacher showed me how to do these problems, but I still am having a hard time cancelling the stuff out once I put it in the brackets. Can anyone show the steps to this for me? Each step please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\eqalign{4\log_3(y+1)+2\log_3(y-1)&{}-3\log_3(y^2-1)-\log_3(y)\cr
  &=\log_3\Bigl(\frac{(y+1)^4(y-1)^2}{(y^2-1)^3y}\Bigr)\cr
  &=\log_3\Bigl(\frac{(y+1)^4(y-1)^2}{(y+1)^3(y-1)^3y}\Bigr)\cr
  &=\log_3\Bigl(\frac{y+1}{(y-1)y}\Bigr)\cr}$$